Pyspark LIT a dictionary into a dataframe
I have a python dict as shown below
cam = {"emp_id":1234, "emp_acct": [6784, 8901], "start_date":"2002-05-06"}

I want to create a new Dataframe by add this as a new column to an existing dataframe and I tried
df = input_df.withColumn("cam_details", lit(cam))

This throws as error as LIT takes only a string..

What's your expected output schema?

As you haven't shared the expected output schema - here's what I think you want:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

input_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,)], "id int")

cam = {"emp_id":1234, "emp_acct": [6784, 8901], "start_date":"2002-05-06"}

cam_schema = "struct<emp_id:string, emp_acct:array<int>, start_date:date>"

df = df.withColumn("cam_details", F.from_json(F.lit(str(cam)), cam_schema))

df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)

Output:
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- cam_details: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- emp_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- emp_acct: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- start_date: date (nullable = true)

+---+--------------------------------+
|id |cam_details                     |
+---+--------------------------------+
|1  |{1234, [6784, 8901], 2002-05-06}|
+---+--------------------------------+

